# Convert JSON with PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm new to Stackoverflow. My problem is convert JSON with PHP to JavaScript. I fetching database to using PHP to create JSON and I want to convert JSON for JavaScript. I would like to use JSON in JavaScript as object (object[1].id). I need you help.

```
    <?php
  $connent = new mysqli('localhost','root','lukasz1248','quiz');
  if ($connent->connect_error != 0)
  {
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_errno());
  }
  $connent->query('SET NAMES utf8');
  $connent->query('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci');
  $result = $connent->query("select * from pytania");

  //put all of the resulting names into a PHP array
  $jsonArray = Array();
  //$how = $result->num_rows;
  //$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  //$row_array = "[";
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['tresc'] = $row['tresc'];
    $row_array['odpa'] = $row['odpa'];
    $row_array['odpb'] = $row['odpb'];
    $row_array['odpc'] = $row['odpc'];
    $row_array['odpd'] = $row['odpd'];
    $row_array['answer'] = $row['answer'];
    $row_array['kategoria'] = $row['kategoria'];
    $row_array['rok'] = $row['rok'];

    array_push($jsonArray,$row_array);
  }
  echo $jsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

  $connent->close();
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var json_array = json_encode('<?php echo $jsonArray ?>')

  window.onload = write;

  var obj_json = JSON.parse(json_array);

  function write(){
    document.getElementById('db').innerHTML = obj_json.length;
  }
</script>
<div id="db"></div>
```

---

I changed it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var json_array = '<?php echo $jsonArray ?>';

  window.onload = write;

  var str = " ";
  var obj_json = JSON.parse(json_array);

  function write(){
    document.getElementById('db').innerHTML = obj_json.length;
  }
</script>
<div id="db"></div>
```

---

Result of this

```
function write(){
    document.getElementById('db').innerHTML = obj_json.length;
}
```

should be 20 at the end my Website http://158.75.89.214/js/test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding it two times.

first place

```
echo $jsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
var json_array = json_encode('<?php echo $jsonArray ?>')
```

Change it to this one

```
var json_array = <?php echo $jsonArray ?>;
```

Comment: I changed it. Does not work!!!

Comment: change it to last statement?

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) is already Javascript code, but we need to output it into Javascript, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($bar); ?>;
</script>
```

It is also useful to wrap it into brackets, to make sure that Javascript understands that this is an object and not a block for instance, wherever it is used.

```
function getJSON($obj) {
    return '('.json_encode($obj).')';
}
```

and then use this.